# write power query or DAX script to compare without case sensitivity (2) text string values while ignoring certain values within text string?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

So I have a task of comparing (2) columns in Power BI, they are both text type data sources

```
One Column            Second Column

ApPle_red 6pk         Apple
apple_green each      Apple
Apple_yellow_organic  Apple
```

is there a way to ignore "_red","_green","_yellow"

current method for case insensitive I am using is:

```
IF(One Column = Second Column, "true", "false")
```

Comment: I know I could extract on delimiter, but this is a basic context for the data I'm looking at, there are many extractions or value replacements that I would have to do, I was wondering if there was a better way

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simple solution using your example.

```
Column = 
VAR aux = UPPER ( LEFT ( 'Table'[One Column]; 5 ) )
RETURN IF ( aux = UPPER ( 'Table'[Second Column] ), "True", "False" )
```

The following is a more complex and generic solution that compares the text before the "_" on the first column with the text on the second column.

```
Column = 
VAR position = SEARCH("_",'Table'[One Column], 1, BLANK()) - 1
VAR aux = UPPER(LEFT('Table'[One Column], position))

Return IF( aux = UPPER('Table'[Second Column]), "True", "False" )
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: is there a way to filter out specific content? The example I have is, as mentioned a basic version of the use case. If there is a way to ignore specific parts of text string would be preferred

Comment: Thats difficult to say without a more accurate data example. If you can provide more information about different cases we can help you.

Comment: Updated column reference to reflect better, just imagine over 30+ variants of produce(besides apples)

Answer (score 2):

In the query editor, you could check if the first column starts with the string in the second column (after converting both to the same case):

```
Text.StartsWith(Text.Lower([One Column]), Text.Lower([Second Column]))
```

The same logic in DAX would be like this:

```
LEFT('Table'[One Column], LEN('Table'[Second Column])) = 'Table'[Second Column]
```

Comment: The code example I use is not case sensitive, the only issue I am having is the presence of text that is not needed for comparison, but the values are still comparable

Comment: The M language is case sensitive though, so you need to normalize. DAX is not case sensitive.